# can't hash a password and set it to field in mongodb schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm experimenting with [a demo blog platform by madhusudhan srinivasa for node.js, express, and mongodb.](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo).  I've created a blog heavily based on his implementation.  But, I'm having trouble with hashing a password and creating a user.  I've attached the model and controller for creating a user since I don't know exactly where the problem is.

My user creation form has user and password fields which are passed into the controller with bodyParser.

My problem is that when i submit the form to create a user, I get an undefined error from the hash validation function, "cannot get length of undefined."

If i comment this hash validation function out, a user is created.  But when i look at the created user in mongodb command line, it doesn't have a hash field at all, but the name and salt fields are set correctly.  However, when I console.log the hash inside encryptPassword(), it seems to output a correctly hashed password.

I have been working on this for hours and am completely at a loss to what the problem could be.

#### model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema
    , crypto = require('crypto')
    , _ = require('underscore')

// user schema

var UserSchema = new Schema ({
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    hash: { type: String, default: '' },         
    salt: { type: String, default: '' }
})

UserSchema
    .virtual('password')
    .set(function(password) {
        this._password = password
        this.salt = this.makeSalt()
        this.hash = this.encryptPassword(password)
    })
    .get(function() { return this._password })


var validatePresenceOf = function (value) {   
    return value && value.length
}

UserSchema.path('name').validate(function(name) {
    return name.length
}, 'you need a name..')

UserSchema.path('name').validate(function(name, cb) {
    var User = mongoose.model('User')

    if (this.isNew || this.isModified('name')) {
    User.find({ name : name }).exec(function(err, users) {
        cb(!err && users.length === 0)
    })
    } else cb(true)
    }, 'name already exists..')

// i get an undefined error at the below function:

UserSchema.path('hash').validate(function(hash) {
    return hash.length
}, 'you need a password...')

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!this.isNew) return next()

    if (!validatePresenceOf(this.password)) {
    next(new Error('invalid password.'))
    } else {
        next()
    }
})

UserSchema.methods = {

    // auth
    authenticate: function(plaintext) {
        return this.encryptPassword(plaintext) === this.hash 
    },

    // salt 
    makeSalt: function() {
        return crypto.randomBytes(128)
    },

    encryptPassword: function (password) {
        if (!password) return ''      
        crypto.pbkdf2(password, this.salt, 2000, 128, function(err, derivedKey) {
            if (err) throw err
            var myhash = derivedKey.toString()
            console.log('hash: ' + myhash)
            return myhash
        })
    } 
}

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

#### controller:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var user = new User(req.body)
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.render('signup', {
                errors: err.errors,
                user: user,
                title: 'SIGN UP'
            })
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err)
            return res.redirect('backend')
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your encryption procedure uses `crypto.pbkdf2`, which is an asynchronous function. This means encryptPassword() will not return your hash when your virtual setter is called. Your hash only gets returned inside of the callback passed to `crypto.pbkdf2` - which is why console.log works in your example.

One way to solve this problem is to change encryptPassword() to make use of pbkdf2's synchronous sibling - `crypto.pbkdf2Sync`. [Link to docs](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2sync_password_salt_iterations_keylen)

Example below (with some error handling):

```
encryptPassword: function (password) {
    if (!password) return ''      
    var encrypted
    try {
        encrypted = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 2000, 128).toString();    
        return encrypted
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle error
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  encryptPassword: function (password) {
        if (!password || !this.salt)
            return '';
        var salt = new Buffer(this.salt, 'base64');
        return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
    }
```